# Split rust library functions across multiple files

Tags: rust

I am using rust to provide faster functions to a webapp through WASM. This involves creating a large number of helper functions, and while I can put them all in a single file (lib.rs), it would quickly get cluttered. To that end, I would like to have the following file hierarchy:

```
|-- src
|   |-- lib.rs
|   |-- helper1.rs
|   |-- helper2.rs
```

Where a file like `helper1.rs` might look like:

```
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn helper1()  {
    // Do something useful
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In lib.rs, include:

```
mod helper1;
mod helper2;
```

This will make the two helper files get linked in.